Read & write back data to the same table [UNSUPPORTED_OVERWRITE.TABLE]
I'm having trouble getting my PySpark application to write an updated DataFrame to a persistent Parquet storage.
I try reading and writing to a stored table
I've followed the usual steps of creating a Spark session, reading/writing DataFrames, and updating the DataFrame in question. When doing it i get the error :

AnalysisException: [UNSUPPORTED_OVERWRITE.TABLE] Can't overwrite the target that is also being read from.

what I am trying to do :



type
action 1
type
action 2 (later)




GET
getting data
GET
getting new data


WRITE
writing data within table TABLE using parquet format
READ
reading TABLE




SCD1
perform SCD1 to update my data




WRITE
writing data within table TABLE




ERR
error : [UNSUPPORTED_OVERWRITE.TABLE]



I think I have a missconception of something ... can anyone point me in the right direction or offer a solution to this problem? I'd greatly appreciate any help or guidance you can provide!
what I have tried
I've tried various methods :

community.cloudera.com > How to simultaneously read from and write to the same parquet file
community.cloudera.com > Cannot overwrite a path that is also being read from 
stackoverflow.com > Read and Write back to same S3 location
doing df1 cache() and count() then del(df) and then df1 write

And also a process to manualy manage files behind but it seems crasy :

stackoverflow.com > Failing to overwrite parquet hive table in pyspark
stackoverflow.com > Pyspark read all files and write it back it to same file after transformation

Here's a simplified code to reproduce :
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Create a Spark session with a connection to my Dockerized Spark cluster
spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://localhost:15002").getOrCreate()

# Declare some useful variables
path          = "/data/user_table"
database_name = "DB_test"
table_name    = "test_users"

# create dataframe and store it
df_ = spark.createDataFrame( 
        [(0,  "Tom"), 
        (0,  "Alice")], 
        ["age", "name"])

# write df
df_.write.mode('overwrite') \
    .option("path", path) \
    .saveAsTable(f"{database_name}.{table_name}")

# read the dataframe back from storage 
df = spark.table(f"{database_name}.{table_name}")

# make something
df1 = df.withColumn('test', F.lit(1))

# save back
df1.write.mode('overwrite') \
    .option("path", path)
    .saveAsTable(f"{database_name}.{table_name}")

I use a Dockerized Spark cluster as follow :
./Spark-Docker
   docker-compose.yml
   Dockerfile
   entrypoint.sh

name: spark-cluster
services:

  spark-master:
    image: my_spark_p3.13
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    environment:
      - PYTHON_VERSION=python3.13
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
      - SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
      - SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS=--packages io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.1,io.delta:delta-storage_2.12:3.2.0 --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
      - SPARK_MASTER_HOST=spark-master
      - PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
      - PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 7077:7077
    networks:
      - spark-network
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data:rw
    entrypoint:
      - "bash"
      - "-c"
      - "/opt/spark/sbin/start-master.sh && tail -f /dev/null"

  spark-connect:
    image: my_spark_p3.13
    container_name: spark-connect
    hostname: spark-connect
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
      - "15002:15002"
    networks:
      - spark-network
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    volumes:
      - ./jars/spark-connect_2.12-3.5.1.jar:/opt/spark/jars/spark-connect_2.12-3.5.1.jar
      - ./jars/delta-spark_2.12-3.2.0.jar:/opt/spark/jars/delta-spark_2.12-3.2.0.jar
      - ./jars/delta-storage-3.2.0.jar:/opt/spark/jars/delta-storage-3.2.0.jar
      - ./data:/data:rw
    command:
      - "bash"
      - "-c"
      - '/opt/spark/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --jars /opt/spark/jars/spark-connect_2.12-3.5.1.jar,/opt/spark/jars/delta-spark_2.12-3.2.0.jar,delta-storage-3.2.0.jar --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" && tail -f /dev/null'
      
  spark-worker:
    image: my_spark_p3.13
    container_name: spark-worker
    hostname: spark-worker
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=16G
      - SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=8081
      - PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
      - PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - spark-network
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data:rw
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    entrypoint:
      - "bash"
      - "-c"
      - "/opt/spark/sbin/start-worker.sh spark://spark-master:7077 && tail -f /dev/null"

networks:
  spark-network:


with jar file obtained from :

delta-storage-3.2.0.jar
delta-spark_2.12-3.2.0.jar
spark-connect_2.12-3.5.1.jar

Dockerfile
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jre-focal

ARG spark_uid=185

RUN groupadd --system --gid=${spark_uid} spark && \
    useradd --system --uid=${spark_uid} --gid=spark spark

RUN set -ex; \
    apt-get update; 

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common; 
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa; 
RUN apt-get install -y python3.13 gnupg2 wget bash tini libc6 libpam-modules krb5-user libnss3 procps net-tools gosu libnss-wrapper; \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark; \
    mkdir /opt/spark/python; \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark/examples; \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark/work-dir; \
    chmod g+w /opt/spark/work-dir; \
    touch /opt/spark/RELEASE; \
    chown -R spark:spark /opt/spark; \
    echo "auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid" >> /etc/pam.d/su; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Apache Spark
# https://downloads.apache.org/spark/KEYS
ENV SPARK_TGZ_URL=https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.5.3/spark-3.5.3-bin-hadoop3.tgz \
    SPARK_TGZ_ASC_URL=https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.5.3/spark-3.5.3-bin-hadoop3.tgz.asc \
    GPG_KEY=0A2D660358B6F6F8071FD16F6606986CF5A8447C

RUN set -ex; \
    export SPARK_TMP="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    cd $SPARK_TMP; \
    wget -nv -O spark.tgz "$SPARK_TGZ_URL"; \
    wget -nv -O spark.tgz.asc "$SPARK_TGZ_ASC_URL"; \
    export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-key "$GPG_KEY" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY"; \
    gpg --batch --verify spark.tgz.asc spark.tgz; \
    gpgconf --kill all; \
    rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" spark.tgz.asc; \
    \
    tar -xf spark.tgz --strip-components=1; \
    chown -R spark:spark .; \
    mv jars /opt/spark/; \
    mv RELEASE /opt/spark/; \
    mv bin /opt/spark/; \
    mv sbin /opt/spark/; \
    mv kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/decom.sh /opt/; \
    mv examples /opt/spark/; \
    ln -s "$(basename /opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_*.jar)" /opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar; \
    mv kubernetes/tests /opt/spark/; \
    mv data /opt/spark/; \
    mv python/pyspark /opt/spark/python/pyspark/; \
    mv python/lib /opt/spark/python/lib/; \
    mv R /opt/spark/; \
    chmod a+x /opt/decom.sh; \
    cd ..; \
    rm -rf "$SPARK_TMP";

COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /opt/entrypoint.sh

ENV SPARK_HOME /opt/spark

WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir

RUN mv /usr/bin/python3.13 /usr/bin/python3

USER spark

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]


entrypoint
apache/spark-docker 3.5.3 entrypoint

delta format made it work
df.write.format('delta') \
   .mode('overwrite') \
   .option("path", path) \
   .saveAsTable(f"{database_name}.{table_name}")


df = spark.table(f"{database_name}.{table_name}").limit(1)

df.write.format("delta")\ 
  .mode("overwrite")\
  .saveAsTable(f"{database_name}.{table_name}")


Overwriting a table that is also being read from is not supported in Spark. See one of the Spark test cases for example (Spark v3.4.4). However, it is possible to do it with INSERT OVERWRITE when overwriting partitions dynamically (SPARK-30112).
I don't see the whole source code, but it looks like you don't need that intermediate writing and reading to disk. So the solution would be to just continue transformations and write the results at the end.
